# Make objects stay attached to sphere's surface while the sphere is shrinking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple game where the player runs around a sphere and has to evade collision with objects that are on its surface. To complicate the game a little bit, I'm trying to shrink the sphere over time.

The main problem that I'm having is that I'm not able to maintain the obstacles that are on the sphere's surface attached to it (the obstacles are spawned on the surface and rotated so that the obstacle's top is looking out from the sphere's center) while shrinking it.

Here's what my planet shrinking code looks like:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.localScale *= 1f - shrinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Here's what the code that I tried to move the obstacles inwards at the same pace as the sphere's shrinking process looks like (this code is also inside the update function):

```
foreach (GameObject obstacle in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Obstacle"))
{
    Vector3 shrinkDirection = obstacle.transform.position - myTransform.position;
    obstacle.transform.Translate(-shrinkDirection * (1f - shrinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

The obstacles just fly away, and I've also tried several things like using the obstacle's localPosition but nothing works. How can I make the obstacles attach to the sphere's surface even while shrinking it? Note: The obstacles are not children of the sphere.

Comment: are the obstacles child of the sphere or independent GameObjects?

Comment: @derHugo they are independent game objects. It says so at the end of the post

Comment: oh ok now I get it ... the obstacles themselves should not shrink right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store all the references to the obstacles when you spawn them something like

```
private List<GameObject> obstacles = new List<GameObject>();

// ...

var obst = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab);
// do your translations and rotation etc

obstacles.Add(obst);
```

than you could have additionally a Dictionary for storing the initial relativ positions like

```
private Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3> obstacleOffsets = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3>();

// ...

obstacleOffsets.Add(obst, obst.transform.position - sphereTranform.position);
```

than you can later use that offset to position the obstacles

```
foreach (GameObject obstacle in obstacles)
{
    var originalOffset = obstacleOffsets[obstacle];
    obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + MergeVectors(originalOffset, transform.localScale);
}
```

---

Ofcourse you could also use only the `Dictionary` like

```
foreach (var kvp in obstacleOffsets)
{
    var obstacle = kvp.Key;
    var originalOffset = kvp.Value;
    obstacle.transform.position = transform.position + MergeVectors(originalOffset, transform.localScale);
}
```

Result (interesting GIF compression ^^)

[image]

---

**Note**

Don't forget that whenever you should destroy an obstacle you have to remove it from the List/Dictionary first!

```
obstacles.Remove(obstacle);
obstacleOffsets.Remove(obstacle);
```

Comment: How could I use this if I didn't want my obstacles to shrink as well?

Comment: yeah just understood your question ^^

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome!

Comment: @EnriqueTorres Glad to help! sorry for the confusion beforehand ;)

Comment: Don't worry! The effort you put into it was awesome! It's always appreciated when someone this nice answers your question! :)